# CSS Button applies to every link, how do I stop this?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to put a link to another website but it applies the whole CSS style for the button to the link, I just want it to be a plain text anchor link..

The CSS is below, sorry that it's alot of code, used a button generator to get it.. I'm new to this!

```
   a.nav {
     width: 80%;
     display: inline-block;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   nav ul {
     padding: 0;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   a:hover {
     color: #900;
     background: #fff;
   }
   a {
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9', GradientType=0);
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     border-radius: 6px;
     border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #666666;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 6px 24px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
   }
   .a:hover {
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
     filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9', GradientType=0);
     background-color: #e9e9e9;
   }
   .myButton:active {
     position: relative;
     top: 1px;
   }
```

Comment: update a, a:hover with your button class ".myButton", ex: .myButton:hover instead a:hover

Comment: @Aru it didn't work man, still applies the style.

Comment: did you remove the styles of (a, a:hover)?? can you post a fiddle sample of your output??

Comment: I can't remove the styles because they're what gives the button the design, I want to keep the buttons the same in the navigation div but for an external link to another website I don't want to apply the CSS format. Sorry, what's fiddle link? @Aru

Comment: post your code in http://jsfiddle.net and save and send us the link (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Above posted css is from where you are posting a link? Is this style coming from the hosted site?

Comment: @Aru http://jsfiddle.net/t5g8vnao/

Comment: @JohnnyC, can u update the fiddle with your html code too??

Comment: @Aru done, as you can see the link in the footer has the button style

Comment: @JohnnyC it seems like you didn't update the code on jsfiddle. You have to press update button at top to save your changes.

Comment: @JohnnyC, I cant see the update (html cde), just put your html code in the html section and click update (near run) and send us the updated link

Comment: @Aru sorry my bad, the link is: http://jsfiddle.net/qe31k4r4/4/

Comment: @JohnnyC, that is what i told u earlier, that the general "a" tag styles overrides, so that you need not to specify styles to a tag directly like a{} instead use a class to override.. I've updated an answer http://jsfiddle.net/qe31k4r4/5/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/devsaurin/qe31k4r4/6/

Answer (score 0):

see the updated answer, you can change the styles for the "`.ext_link`" as per your need

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qe31k4r4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have styled the anchor link with your button style, all `<a></a>` tags with look like a button. To simply fix this, presuming you only want the button style applied to your nav, append a `nav` selector like so:

```
nav a { 
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
     filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9', GradientType=0);
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     border-radius: 6px;
     border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #666666;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 6px 24px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
   }
```

This way you only style the anchor tags that are within your nav.
[JSFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/qe31k4r4/7/)